# React component keeps updating

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I can't get my `componentDidUpdate()` stopping from updating. We have a Switch/Route that updates the URL, but the component itself doesn't update on its own. And with all the `componentDidUpdate()` which I got to work, keeps updating forever.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { Id } = this.props.match.params
    this.props.Request({ Id })
  }

  //Works but keeps updating!
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.Id !== prevProps.Id) {
      const { Id } = this.props.match.params
      this.props.Request({ Id })
    }
    return false;
  }

// and for our Switch
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/foobar/:Id"
    render={(props) => (
      <DetailComponent some={some} props={props} />
    )}
  />
</Switch
```

The component needs to change its state when clicking a sidebar button which (Link of react-router-dom) changes the URL. I do see a Location change in the redux tools.

I have tried multiple solutions but nothing seemed to work, or it doesn't do anything at all (and only refreshing the page will load the right state) or it keeps updating every part of a second (which I can see by a loading component that renders while loading new state.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an inline function in a `<Route>`, use the `render` prop instead of `component`. The reason is outlined in the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) (emhpasis mine):

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to create a new [React element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html) from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, **you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component**. When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop (below).

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/foobar/:Id"
    render={(props) => (
      <DetailComponent some={some} props={props} />
    )}
  />
</Switch
```

Comment: True and i have changed that. Thanks. However it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Be sure to edit your question to include that change :)